# Compare tool that can mask differences?

Tags: user-interface, diff, compare, mask

I do a lot of file comparisons (source, logs etc.) and need to mask certain sections e.g. dates / times / line numbers which cause every line to be different.

Beyond Compare allows you to pre-process the files but then you have to write pieces of code to do this.

Is there a GUI type tool that allows you to mask sections of the file via a filter e.g. skip columns 10 - 16, skip data between word x and word y etc.?

Comment: Why is this voted down and marked for close?

Comment: Hey, how does this work?

There is a question asked just now i.e. "XML compare tool that can “Tidy” the XML and ignore differences in attributes." that didn't get any "down" or "close" votes and it seems exactly the same to me?

Comment: on uservoice there was a proposal for asking downvoters for a reason. It got shot down, but if more people vote for it, Jeff/Joel may reconsider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).  It has the ability to filter lines based on regular expressions.

Comment: I use WinMerge a lot and had no idea it had this filtering capability!  Thanks for educating me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any GUI tools, but if you're in a unix environment, you can pipe both files through sed or awk

```
#Example: skip first word
sed 's/^[^[:space:]]*//' yourfile1 >file1.tmp
sed 's/^[^[:space:]]*//' yourfile2 >file2.tmp
diff file1.tmp file2.tmp
```